# Is there a simple way to detect mouse or keyboard activity in Linux/Xorg/Qt4/Kde4?

Tags: event-handling, keyboard, mouse, x11, xorg

Is there a simple way to detect mouse or keyboard activity in Linux or Xorg or Qt4 or Kde4 environment? Obviously not only on a particular window but in the entire Xorg desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XScreenSaver extension (`man Xss`). It can provide you with values into this struct using the function `XScreenSaverQueryInfo`:

```
   typedef struct {
       Window window;                /∗ screen saver window */
       int state;                    /∗ ScreenSaver{Off,On,Disabled} */
       int kind;                     /∗ ScreenSaver{Blanked,Internal,External} */
       unsigned long til_or_since;   /∗ milliseconds */
       unsigned long idle;           /∗ milliseconds */
       unsigned long event_mask;     /∗ events */
   } XScreenSaverInfo;
```

> The idle field specifies the number of milliseconds since the last input was received from the user on any of the input devices.

I don't know about a Qt only solution for this.

Comment: doesn't this imply that you've got to regularly poll for changes to this structure?

Comment: you can also seem to register for events regarding the screensaver. but doesn't look like this includes an event for every activity of the user.

Answer (score 0):

look for expectk, it's open source and will provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try XRecord (grabing key&mouse is another common solution but it has issues with other applications grabbing).

Here is some link I used some time ago: http://mtoader.blogspot.com/2005/02/you-want-recording-x11-event-recording.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the guts of the Qt4 or KDE API's.

However in general terms, on any X11 system keyboard or mouse input is only delivered to the *active* window, unless you call the underlying `XGrabMouse`, `XGrabKeyboard`, etc functions.

Of course, once you've done that, no other window can receive those input events, so you have to make very sure that there's a way for your program to release the mouse and/or keyboard input once you're done.